# Apache subdomain and hosts rewrite

Tags: subdomain, apache-2.4, virtualhost

So here's the basics of what I'm trying to do. I have 2 servers, one live and one dev. Live has 2 domains attached to it. For simplicity sake we will call them a.live.com and b.live.com. Dev has a public IP address, but it doesn't have a host attached to it. So I can access dev by going to 11.22.33.44, but I can't actually use a host name to access it. (Domains obviously are pointing only to live server)

I just created the dev server, but I'm having trouble being able to access the two subdomains. I have a hosts file setup on my machine which points the host to the domain:

```
11.22.33.44 a.live.com
11.22.33.44 b.live.com
```

I have both of the sites enabled (they both appear in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled) but for some reason whenever I go to b.live.com it tries and access a.live.com in my dev server. So I know the host is correctly pointing to the right server. Additionally, when I disable a.live.com then b.live.com correctly goes to the correct subdomain. So it looks as though apache is somehow taking whatever domain I put in and is somehow ordering them in whatever order it wants... Here is an example of my vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName a.live.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/a/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The b vhost file is exactly the same, but with the obvious changes.

Some additional notes: Dev uses apache 2.4 while live uses 2.2 which is why I can't just copy and paste things =/ (We plan on eventually pushing live to 2.4, but we first wanted to run a dev server and make sure everything works properly)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not to familiar with apache rewriting so not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

I've done some searching on server fault and here are some answers to questions normally asked:
I ran

```
apachectl restart
```

after altering everything. (From what I understand graceful sometimes misses things, so I did a full restart instead)
I also ran configtest and it said the Syntax was ok

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The summary is a bit misleading, is suggests an Apache mod_rewrite problem, while it isn't.

Does your main httpd.conf enable NameVirtualHosts?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

If this is enabled:

To do further analysis please enable logging on your Apache(s). Each vhost should log to a different logfile and try access your servers from your client with some debugging options, for example using curl:

```
curl -vvv http://a.live.com/
curl -vvv http://b.live.com/
```

This way you could find out, which IP your client is really connecting to and which virtual host on this IP is really accesses.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to cause confusion. NameVirtualHost was deprecated in 2.4 so it's not used. I already have logging enabled. When I have a and b enabled, then the a log gets hit. When I disable a, then the b log gets hit. (In both instances I hit http://b.live.com/)

Comment: How I know NameVirtualHost has no effect: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html (says 'The NameVirtualHost directive no longer has any effect, other than to emit a warning. Any address/port combination appearing in multiple virtual hosts is implicitly treated as a name-based virtual host')